# Can a foreign key refer to a subset of parent table's rows? (Value domain constraint)

Tags: oracle, foreign-key

Our project massively uses so-called (enumerated) *data value domains*, or *(coded) value domains*, as defined by the [Australian Institute of Health and Welfare](https://meteor.aihw.gov.au/content/237553), and [in The Data Administration Newsletter](https://tdan.com/data-value-domains/5066). I find that the definition which best matches our usage is [Esri's](https://support.esri.com/en-us/gis-dictionary/coded-value-domain), i.e. a code to description map.

For example, we may have the following.

Domain **PROVINCES**:

- AB, Alberta
- BC, British Columbia
- ...
- NB, New Brunswick
- ...
- YK, Yukon

Domain **ROLES**:

- ANL, Analyst
- ARCT, Architect
- BOSS, Manager
- TECH, Technician

We use a single table to store all value domains. Basically, that **DOMAINS** table looks like this:

| DOMAIN_NAME | CODE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PROVINCES | AB | Alberta |
| PROVINCES | BC | British Columbia |
| ... | ... | ... |
| PROVINCES | NB | New Brunswick |
| ... | ... | ... |
| PROVINCES | YK | Yukon |
| ROLES | ANL | Analyst |
| ROLES | ARCT | Architect |
| ROLES | BOSS | Manager |
| ROLES | TECH | Technician |

Codes tend to be abbreviations, but serve as semi-intelligible identifiers which "child tables" refer to, so suppose we have a table to store employees with their location and role, the **EMPLOYEES** table could look like this:

| NAME | PROVINCE | ROLE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | AB | ANL |
| Bob | BC | ARCT |
| John | NB | BOSS |

Our problem is that we don't actually have parent/child tables since referential integrity is not enforced with foreign keys (from `EMPLOYEES` to `DOMAINS`).

If we had individual `PROVINCES` and `ROLES` tables, `EMPLOYEES` could easily enforce integrity with:

```
PROVINCE VARCHAR2(100) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PROVINCES(CODE),
ROLE VARCHAR2(100) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ROLE(CODE)
```

But as far as we know, all we can do with our architecture is:

```
PROVINCE VARCHAR2(100) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DOMAINS(CODE),
ROLE VARCHAR2(100) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES DOMAINS(CODE)
```

...which doesn't prevent `EMPLOYEES.ROLE` from containing a province code (like "AB", which isn't a valid role code).

With our architecture, does Oracle Database 19 allow doing something like:

```
FOREIGN KEY('PROVINCES', PROVINCE) REFERENCES DOMAINS(DOMAIN_NAME, CODE)
FOREIGN KEY('ROLES', ROLE) REFERENCES DOMAINS(DOMAIN_NAME, CODE)
```

...so that a column refers to a single domain? If not, I would be curious to know which other RDBMS engines allow that.

Comment: Thanks very much for your fix Rohit. I struggle to understand how my original was broken; I could have sweared the tables displayed fine when I was writing!

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by adding a set of dummy columns for your domain literals and using a set of two-column FKs that use them. Invisible virtual columns are best as they wouldn't be visible to anyone not explicitly requesting them, nor would they take any space. Example:

```
create table domains 
  (domain_name varchar2(30), 
   code varchar2(30), 
   description varchar2(100), 
   constraint pk_domains primary key (domain_name,code))
/
create table employees 
  (name varchar2(100), 
   province varchar2(30),
   role varchar2(30),
   province_literal varchar2(30) invisible AS ('PROVINCE') virtual,  
   role_literal varchar2(30) invisible AS ('ROLE') virtual,
   constraint fk_employees_role foreign key (role_literal,role) references domains(domain_name,code),
   constraint fk_employees_province foreign key (province_literal,province) references domains(domain_name,code))
/
    
insert into domains values ('PROVINCE','CA','California');
insert into domains values ('ROLE','CEO','Chief Executive Officer');
insert into employees values ('Sam','CA','CEO'); --> succeeds
insert into employees values ('Sam','CA','CA'); --> errors on fk_employees_role
insert into employees values ('Sam','CEO','CEO'); --> errors on fk_employees_province
insert into employees values ('Sam','AL','CEO'); --> errors on fk_employees_province
insert into employees values ('Sam','CA','CHEF'); --> errors on fk_employees_role
```

Answer (score -1):

None of the SQL DBMSes (that I know of) support such syntax, and if they did, they would be violating the SQL standard.

You (plural) have made the wrong design decision originally, now you'll have to live with the consequences. You could use triggers to enforce the constraint, but you can't do that in a declarative manner.

Comment: Thanks
I assume when you talk about violating SQL, you mean the current SQL version does not specify such keys, right? You're not saying a DBMS extending SQL to support such keys would be technically incompatible with SQL?

By the way, we are a small IT team with no access to the not-so-cheap SQL standard, so I couldn't check it.